# python - i need to fill dataframe with for loop using sum()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how are?

i need to complete my dataframe with data returned by a sum function.

so, I have this code that creates my dataframe:

```
columns = ['hom_doloso', 'lesao_corp_morte', 'latrocinio',
       'hom_por_interv_policial', 'tentat_hom', 'lesao_corp_dolosa', 'estupro',
       'hom_culposo', 'lesao_corp_culposa', 'roubo_comercio',
       'roubo_residencia', 'roubo_veiculo', 'roubo_carga', 'roubo_transeunte',
       'roubo_em_coletivo', 'roubo_banco', 'roubo_cx_eletronico',
       'roubo_celular', 'roubo_conducao_saque', 'roubo_apos_saque',
       'roubo_bicicleta', 'outros_roubos', 'total_roubos', 'furto_veiculos',
       'furto_transeunte', 'furto_coletivo', 'furto_celular',
       'furto_bicicleta', 'outros_furtos', 'sequestro',
       'extorsao', 'sequestro_relampago', 'estelionato', 'apreensao_drogas',
       'posse_drogas', 'trafico_drogas', 'apreensao_drogas_sem_autor', 'ameaca']

index = [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001,
       2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012,
       2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019] 
new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
```

Then i need to fill each column in this DataFrame with a aggregation function, like:

```
new_df.hom_doloso = df_clean.groupby('vano').hom_doloso.sum()
```

returning:

```
new_df.head()
      hom_doloso   lesao_corp_morte   latrocinio  ...
1991    7518              NaN             NaN
1992    7635              NaN             NaN
1993    7720              NaN             NaN
1994    8408              NaN             NaN
```

The above code only completes one column of the dataframe, i really don't want to write all this columns names, so i tried to use For Loop, but i can't do that

```
for column_name in columns:
  new_df.column_name = df_clean.groupby('vano').column_name.sum()
```

The column_name in this for need to be replace by the each column name

df_clean: `df_clean.shape: (344, 56)`

````
df_clean.head()```
      vano    hom_doloso   lesao_corp_morte   latrocinio  ...
0     1991    7518              0.0             18
1     1992    7635              0.0             17
2     1993    7720              0.0             16
3     1994    8408              0.0             15
````

The new_df will only have these columns in variable called columns, which df_clean also have.

I need to groupby by 'vano' to return the sum of each column.

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: I believe we would need more information to solve this problem. Could you share a bit of what df_clean looks like? Does it have all the same columns as new_df? Will the groupby() argument be 'vano' for each column?

Comment: I edited my question to add more information, if anyone needs more, let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No looping needed.
Let's try something like this:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(5,5)), columns=[*'ABCDE'])
df['grp'] = ['A','A','A','B','B']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D   E grp
0  66  92  98  17  83   A
1  57  86  97  96  47   A
2  73  32  46  96  25   A
3  83  78  36  96  80   B
4  68  49  55  67   2   B
```

Now, let's reshape dataframe stack all columns we want to sum, set index on all columns that we don't want to sum and use groupby with levels.  Lastly, unstack the inner most level to get columns back.

```
df.set_index('grp').stack().groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().unstack()
```

or

```
df.set_index('grp').stack().sum(level=[0,1]).unstack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  grp    A    B    C    D    E
0   A  196  210  241  209  155
1   B  151  127   91  163   82
```

Comment: Ok, thank u. But u can explain more this sum(level=[0,1]), I did not understand what this level do

Comment: Sure.... sum(level=[0,1]) does the exact same as groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().  It is summing based on index levels zero and level one.  Just a shorter way to do a groupby some on index levels.